# How to set access token to expire in seconds

Tags: token, keycloak, access-token, keycloak-services, redhat-sso

I have an issue to configuring Redhat Single SigOn (RHSSO) or Keycloak token expiration in seconds, about 30 seconds.

I just found the configuration in minutes. There is a way to adjust it to seconds?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Keycloak Admin Console](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#admin-console) it is not possible; Keycloak allows to specify the access token expiration time in `Minutes`, `Hours` or `Days`, but not in seconds:

[image]

Albeit, when one requests a token, the expiration time is display in seconds, namely:

```
{"access_token":"...","expires_in":60,"...}
```

The least amount of time that you can set via Admin Console is `1` minute. To be honest, I fail to see what would be the great benefit of having 30 seconds instead of 1 minute.

In the Admin Console, if one tries to specify 0.1 (or 0,1) minutes an error is displayed

[image]

Now that being said, it *seems* that you can use the [Rest Full API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html) to get around that restriction. First, request a token on behalf of the admin, extract its access token (let us called `$ACCESS_TOKEN`). And then call the following endpoint:

```
PUT <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<REALM_NAME>
```

with the following data

```
'{"accessTokenLifespan":30}'
```

Now if you request a token for a client on the Realm `REALM_NAME` you will get the following:

```
{"access_token":"...","expires_in":30,"...}
```

30 seconds as expiration time for the access token.

Now, I have not tested this, so it is up to you to find out if everything still works as it should.